# Пропала кнопка displays с вкладки Game

Tags: unity3d, gui, ui

Вот ищу не могу найти этот переключатель, также на камерах нету кнопки на какой дисплей выводить.
Юнити 2019, также стало и юнити 5.6.
Открываю пример проекта и кнопки появляются.
В чем причина этого полтергейса?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для переключения между камерами в редакторе есть кнопка выбора, у меня она пропала) на двух юнити) для проверки загрузил пример проекта-а там это кнопка есть.     Пробывал ставить несколько камер-не выходит.

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Эти кнопки пропадают при выборе платформы андроид) при возврате на пк они возвращаются